# How to make class binding on an angular table row using table row index to match elements of component array

Tags: html, angular

I have an array field consisting of numeric digits in the angular component.

```
venuesRunning: any = [13, 14];
```

I need to activate a class on the row of the table within the HTML template based on a condition which checks if the index of the row is within the component array(`venuesRunning`). Below is the code I tried to use

```
<tr
  *ngFor="let v of mf.data; index as i" 
  [class.bg-primary]="i in venuesRunning">
  {{ v }}
</tr>
```

I am getting syntax error stating

> [Angular] Parser Error: Unexpected token 'in' at column 3 in [i in venuesRunning] in @64:53

What am I doing wrong? Can someone correct me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  venuesRunning: any = [2, 6];
  mf = {
    data: [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
      '5',
      '6'
    ]
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mf.data = this.mf.data.map((item, index) => ({ display: item, toApplyClass: this.venuesRunning.includes(index) }));
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<tr 
  *ngFor="let v of mf.data; index as i"
  [class.bg-primary]="v.toApplyClass">
  {{ v.display }}
</tr>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/update-angular-input-on-blur?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Actually the provided solution did not work. [class.bg-primary]="venuesRunning[i]"  is activating based on indexs of venuesRunning. If i pass [13, 14] as component array, rows 0 and 1 of the table are getting assigned to the class(bg-primary). I tried this scenario on your working sample as well. It's behaving weird.

Comment: @user464159, please check the updated answer. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something but isn't enough just to change your code to:

```html
<tr
  *ngFor="let v of mf.data; index as i" 
  [class.bg-primary]="venuesRunning.indexOf(i) !== -1">
  {{ v }}
</tr>
```